# Smex in Evil mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I'm using Evil mode and would now like to use smex so that when I press ":" in evil mode I get smex. This is what I have now in my Emacs file:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd ";") (kbd ":"))
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd ":") (kbd ";"))
```

This is obviously not enough to enter smex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following bindings allow you to use `:` to get `smex` and `;` to get to Ex mode, which is what you seem to want from your example:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map ":" 'smex)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map ";" 'evil-ex)
```

(Note that normal state inherits from motion state.)